# How to prevent react-router from messing up API route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm implementing nested URLs with react-router. I have created a dashboard component and a Navbar that has link to different components. The challenge is that all the link in the Navbar works except one, when I click on the Navbar link, it takes me back to the home page. Below is the structure of my route

```
//App.js

<Switch>
            <Route path="/c">
              <LoggedInComponent />
            </Route>
            <Route>
              <LoggedOutComponent />
            </Route>
  </Switch>
```

```
// LoggedInComponent/routing.js

return (
    <div>
      <Switch>
        
       <PropsRoute
        
          path="/c/employee"
          component={Employee}
         
        /> 
       <PropsRoute
      
          path="/c/attendance"
          component={Attendance}
         
        /> 
        <PropsRoute
       exact
          path="/c/wagesCalculator"
          component={ WagesCalculator}
          
        /> 
     
     
        <PropsRoute
         path=""
          component={Dashboard}
          
        />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
```

When I click on the "Employee link" , I get a 404 error because the route changes from GET /api/v1/employee/ into GET /c/api/v1/employee/  and obviously it wouldn't match with the endpoint. How do i prevent the router from adding "/c/" on my route

Comment: What's your Employee link's `to` prop looks like?

Comment: i  really dont understand what you mean by link to prop , but i have this though  {  link: "/c/employee"}.... the path on my routing.js and my Navbar.js  are same

Comment: Could you put together a runnable example that can reproduce the issue you're talking about?

Comment: ok, i will do that